# Backbone view: el and events

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am trying to play around with Backbone and have trouble with Views, in particular with "el" and events. I noticed I'm not the first one, but unfortunatelly could not find an optimal answer to my questions.

My base relevant code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script data-main="main" src="js/require.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="login"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

VIEW:

```
var view = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: $("#login"),

        initialize: function() {
            this.el.html('<div>click here</div>');         // TypeError: this.el.html is not a function 
        }
.....
```

**Question 1:**

Please note the comment in the initialize() function, that's error registered by Firebug when I load this code.

But, when I only remove the "el" config and instead put the corresponding assignement in initialize() the run-time error is gone!

```
var view = Backbone.View.extend({
            //  "el" is now removed 

        initialize: function() {
            this.el = $("#login");                       // explicit assignement
            this.el.html('<div>click here</div>');       // appends the div correctly
        }
.....
```

**Question 2:**
In both of these examples if I specify events in View's events config, the event never fires:

```
events: {
            "click":          "tryLogin"
          },
          ...
```

Please enlighten me! :)

Answer (score 2):

The specific problem you're having is that `this.el` is not a jQuery object, and it has no `.html` method.  That's what `this.$el` is for; `this.el` is a raw DOM element and `this.$el` is the jQuery-wrapped version of that object. You should not overwrite `el` with a jQuery-selected element.

The real problem you're having is that you're trying to modify the DOM in `initialize`.

If, in `initialize`, you want to access a DOM element that is already in the DOM, you need to pass an `el:` option to the view's constructor. Generally you shouldn't do this though. Your view should do its DOM manipulation in its `render` method.

From [the docs](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor):

> If you'd like to create a view that references an element already in the DOM, pass in the element as an option: `new View({el: existingElement})`

In practice I've found that `el` and `$el` are still available, but you should avoid using them in `initialize` regardless. Stick to modifying the DOM in `render`, which is specifically where your view's "drawing" code is meant to go:

```js
var view = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#login',
  render: function () {
    this.$el.append('<h1>What!</h1>');
    return this;
  }
});


$(function () {
  new view().render();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js"></script>

<div id="login"></div>
```

In regards to Question 2, I cannot reproduce your problem. The following works exactly as expected:

```js
var View = Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#login',
  events: {
    'click': 'onClick'
  },
  onClick: function () {
    alert('click!');  
  },
  render: function () {
    this.$el.append('<h1>What!</h1>');
  }
});

new View().render();
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.7.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js"></script>

    <div id="login"></div>
```

Comment: As far as Question 2 goes, if you're directly messing around with `this.el` in a view then your events will get trashed because `delegateEvents` won't get called to attach the events to the new `el`. However, if you use [`setElement`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-setElement) to change the `el`, everything gets set up: new `el`, new `$el`, and `delegateEvents` is called to move the event bindings.

Comment: Looks like I'm losing some details here. There are apperently so many contradictory information around el and $el. In the TODO example (from the backbone official site: http://backbonejs.org/docs/todos.html) we have such a config: el: $("#todoapp")! There are other examples as well, for example the typical way of creating the view (new View({ el: $("#container") })   You say this is wrong. What's the truth? :)

Comment: @Aleks I've quoted directly from the current documentation, take it or leave it

Comment: @meagar I've read it long ago, but as I told, the info seems to be contradictory. If ""take it or leave it is all you can say, then I leave it.